# How to Listen for all Jquery Animations related to an object to be complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

scenario:

- An animation can be called multiple times.
- The animation is called by another event such as a click event.
- The animation should not fire until it is sure that all other animation events involving this structure are complete.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/xo6ngbfz/

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

    console.log('run');

        jQuery("#animation-object").bind("fire-hide", function () {
            jQuery(this).toggle();
        });

        jQuery('#element').on('click', function () {
            console.log('click');
            jQuery('*').trigger("fire-hide");
        });

});
```

Further understanding:

This is a very simple animation; but say for instance someone had a set of tiles. These tiles slide up and down on the screen after a link has been clicked on.

If we do not wait for all animations to be complete, the slide effect could stop half way through the animation and revert to whatever animation was last clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I did an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/lmendizabal/qa69pg5c/2/) with your code. I hope it could be useful for you!

The key was use a counter for total animations you have and pass a function as a callback for each one:

```
jQuery(this).toggle("slow", animationFinished);
```

You shoud do it for each jquery function you want to it notify you that it was finished.

(when function not accept callback, it is enough call animationFinished() after it, see line 14 of the example).

When the counter of animations has finished is equal to the total animation counter, then a function is called and the counter is reseted.

It is no the best way to do it, because each time you add an animation, you have to modify the totalAnimations counter, but at least is an option for now.

Comment: This is a good example, but I don't think it captures the essence of what I need to do.

I need the function bound to "fire-hide" to be aware of itself being complete or not and only fire itself after itself is done with whatever it was doing previously.